# Getter access data that is Excluded by class-transformer on mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, class-transformer

I have the following class

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Event {
  ...

  @Prop({ type: [SponsorSchema], default: [] })
  @Type(() => Sponsor)
  // @Expose({ groups: ['different.group'] }) <--- or this
  @Exclude()
  sponsors: Sponsor[]

  @Expose({ groups: ['event.list'] })
  get total_sponsored(): number {
    return this.sponsors.reduce((total, sponsor) => total + sponsor.value, 0)
  }

  ...
}
```

The `total_sponsored` variable just show when `sponsors` is with Expose() decorator, so when I use Expose() with different groups (or Exclude()), `total_sponsored` can't access `this.sponsors` as it is `undefined`.

I'm using a Interceptor that has the following code:

```
return plainToInstance(classToIntercept, document, {
    excludeExtraneousValues: true,
    groups: groups
})
```

Before stepping into the Interceptor, `sponsors` has data and `total_sponsored` don't exists. After that, `sponsors` is undefined and `total_sponsored` gives and error because it can't use .reduce on a undefined.

How can I access `sponsors` data for `total_sponsored` without it showing on the final object (after Interceptor)?